# Create directory and files with one command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to make a command/function to `mkdir` and `touch` my directory and files quickly.

---

Terminal: `cd PROJECT`:

```
PROJECT
```

Terminal: `quickcreate home index.js style.css ...`. The tree looks like:

```
PROJECT __ home __ index.html
                \_ style.css
                \_ ...
```

Do manually:

```
mkdir home
touch home/index.html
touch home/style.css
touch home/...
```

---

I want to write a command like this:

```
function quickcreate {
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "No arg supplied!"
  return 0
else
  mkdir $1
  # how can I do with S2, S3, .... to touch S1/S2 S1/S3...?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `-p`.

```
qc() { local p="$1";
  if [[ -n "$p" ]];
  then mkdir -p "$p" # can be any full or relative path;
  else echo "Use: qc <dirpath> [f1[..fN]]"; return 1;
  fi;
  shift;
  for f; do touch "$p/$f"; done;
}

$: qc
Use: qc <dirpath> [f1[..fN]]

$: cd /tmp
$: qc a/b/c 5 4 3 2 1    # relative path
$: qc a/b                # no files; dir already exists; no problem
$: qc /tmp/a/b/c/d 3 2 1 # full path that partially exists
$: find a                # all ok
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/1
a/b/c/2
a/b/c/3
a/b/c/4
a/b/c/5
a/b/c/d
a/b/c/d/1
a/b/c/d/2
a/b/c/d/3
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot the -p. It's absolutely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift` to remove positional arguments one by one.

Don't forget to double quote the directory and file names so the script works for names containing whitespace, too.

```
mkdir "$1"
dir=$1
shift
while (( $# )) ; do
    touch "$dir/$1"
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method you can use for what you want, that is using **arrays**:

```sh
function quickcreate {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No arg supplied!"
    return 0
  else
    dir="${@::1}"
    files=(${@:1})

    mkdir "$dir"

    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
      touch $dir/$file
    done 
}
```